# Создание двигающихся объектов в Java

Tags: java, swing

Дали задание создать ( нарисовать ) двигающийся объект в Java.
Конкретное задание нарисовать фигуру относительно базовой точки ( базовая точка это ? )

[image: Сама структура которую необходимо сделать]

Выше изображено объект который необходимо воссоздать, и задание после - Анимировать по вертикальной линии. При столкновении с горизонтальными стенками, фигура начинает двигаться назад.

---

Как я понял рисовать надо при помощи Java Swing. Может кто объяснить подробнее как мне это реализовать ( ранее не сталкивался с графиков в Java в целом ).

Answer (score 1):

1. Сначала прочтите что такое [двойная буферизация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)
2. Далее разбейте свое изображение на [спрайты](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82_(%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)) - их у вас на глазок 6 (голова, хвост, плавники, туловище и глаза)
3. Напишите методы которые рисуют каждый отдельный спрайт отдельно
4. Далее напишите метод который рисует из спрайтиков рыбку принимая в качестве параметра координаты рыбки (это и есть ваша базовая точка)
5. Далее рисуете по таймеру движение по координатам.

Остальное вы легко нагуглите.